Dragging image from Firefox to Nautilus (22.04) has different behavior on Ubuntu 24.04

In Ubuntu 22.04 LTS dragging an image from Firefox (e.g. from Facebook, Twitter, etc. or from a server as in my case) to a Nautilus folder results in the image with the information of its modification date (which in my case is the creation date on the server or on Facebook which is the date it was uploaded).

In Ubuntu 24.04 LTS doing the same action results in the image being renamed as "IMAGE DROPPED", the information of its modification date is overwritten with the creation date in the computer's file system, i.e. the current time of the user.


NOTE: The action described in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is only possible in WAYLAND. In X11 it is not possible.

This was discovered after my colleagues and I migrated to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS from the current one. We had to go back to the previous one for practical reasons.

If you're wondering why we use this action, it's because it makes it easier to be aware if the image was modified on the server. For example, we drag images to our folder to later use them in our LaTeX documents. These images are renamed with a script to use their modification date which is actually the creation date on the server.

Sorry for using Facebook or Twitter as an example, as for me it's the
easiest way to demonstrate the change between Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and
24.04 LTS. Unless you have a server from which you display images.

In the images below you can see that I drag the image to a folder, this image has the original modification date (in this case it matches the date of the Facebook post which is "April 8, 2024")

Questions:
What I would like to know is if it's possible to have the same behavior of Ubuntu 22.04LTS on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS or is it an irreversible change.
Thank you very much in advance for any help.



Can you report back if the error exists in other file managers like nemo? Then we may be able to decide if this is a nautilus regression or a 24.04 bug. GNOME Developers often remove many useful features because they do not align with their "vision".

Hi Archisman Panigrahi, thank you very much for answering my question. Regarding what you indicate in your comment, it is indeed a regression in Nautilus since this behavior works in "THUNAR" and "NEMO". However, always in WAYLAND.
Perhaps the developers can fix it since this behavior was present in previous versions of Nautilus.
Likewise, what you said will allow us to migrate to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with the hope that the Ubuntu developers may be able to fix it in future maintenance versions.
First of all, thank you again for your comment, it was very helpful.
Have a great day!

Nautilus is maintained by GNOME developers, not Ubuntu developers. I suggest you to either stick with a previous LTS version of Ubuntu, or use a different flavor of Ubuntu like Ubuntu MATE or Xubuntu (or Debian), or regular 24.04 with nemo. This is a GNOME-specific issues. It is a GNOME decision, there is really nothing Ubuntu developers can do about that. Also, this site is run by volunteers, this is not a Ubuntu developers' site/bug reporting site. You can open a bug report with Nautilus in GitLab, but GNOME developers may decide to ignore it, because they already removed the feature.

Hi, thank you very much for your comment, I will take it into account. I will also report it as a bug in the Nautilus (Gnome) gitlab. Thanks for your help, I hope everything goes well for you.
